# Linking External Javascript with drupal_set_html_head

Tags: javascript

I want to add the below external javascript file to the head of my Drupal 6 site.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
stLight.options({
    publisher: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});
</script>
```

I want to know if it's OK to do somethng like this, as it's not working at the moment.

```php
function template_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  drupal_set_html_head('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>');
  drupal_set_html_head('<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}); </script>');
}
```

Someone should kindly assist me feature the links of the external file in the header of every page of my site.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all you need to add is `$vars['head']=drupal_get_html_head();` after your code above so that the $head variable passed to your page.tpl.php is updated.  If you are doing anything "interesting" with your header, you may need to change that to a `.=` instead so that it is added to $head instead of just replacing it.